# Vert.x HTTP/2 ALPN not available for JDK SSL/TLS engine

Tags: vert.x

With Vert.x 3.4.2 and the `runtime "io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.5.Final"` dependency, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: ALPN not available for JDK SSL/TLS engine
io.vertx.core.VertxException: ALPN not available for JDK SSL/TLS engine
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.SSLHelper.resolveEngineOptions(SSLHelper.java:89)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.SSLHelper.<init>(SSLHelper.java:150)
    at io.vertx.grpc.VertxChannelBuilder.build(VertxChannelBuilder.java:148)
    at uk.ashleybye.grpc.tls.Client.start(Client.kt:22)
    at io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle.start(AbstractVerticle.java:111)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$8(DeploymentManager.java:434)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:445)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However, if I use the `runtime "io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:1.1.33.Fork26"` dependency, no problem. Is this a Vert.x/Netty version compatability issue, or is something else at play?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you always use the correct version of Netty tc-native with Vert.x.

Comment: It is work with this version.

```implementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.25.Final'```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vertx 3.8.1. Use the version below.

```
implementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.25.Final'
```